# How to export all article as RDf of a site

Tags: sparql, rdf

Can anyone help me with RDF extraction

I have an application in which there are many articles in which I add the RDF syntax as **schema.org** now I want all my RDF data in SPARQL. 
How can I do that?

any suggestion is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: *"now I want all my RDF data in SPARQL"* - what? SPARQL is a query language for RDF, your sentence doesn't make sense. Load the RDF data into a tripe store, then you can write SPARQL queries that return whatever you want

Comment: Oops. ok got it

Comment: Now I am using Virtuoso for triple store